# How to make filter by name and address in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm new with React.js. I'm making filter by name and address but I don't know how to do this with separate components. I have main component Speakers - in this component I receive json and send this data to Filter and List. In List.js I get data and display all speaker items(all json). In Filter I want to make search by name and address. I don't know how to bind component filter and list. I'll appreciate if you help me. I know that Redux help working with data in React but I want to understand how to do this without it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRhKm.jpg)

Speakers.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Filters from './Filters';
import List from './List';

class Speakers extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            items: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({isLoading: true});
        fetch("https://randomapi.com/api/6de6abfedb24f889e0b5f675edc50deb?fmt=raw&sole")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        items: result,
                        isLoading: false
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                }
            )
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="speakers">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <Filters getItems={this.state} />
                    <List getItems={this.state} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Speakers;
```

List.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class List extends Component {
    render() {
        const {items, isLoading} = this.props.getItems;
        if (isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading ...</p>;
        } 

        return (
            <div className="speakers__list">
                <div className="row">
                    {items.map((item, index) => (
                        <div className="col-md-3" key={index}>
                            <div className="card form-group shadow">
                                <div className="card-body text-center">
                                    <h5 className="card-title">{item.first} {item.last}</h5>
                                    <p>{item.email}</p>
                                    <p>{item.address}</p>
                                    <p>{item.balance}</p>
                                    <p>{item.created}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default List;
```

Filters.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Filters extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="filters">
                <div className="alert shadow">
                    <form>
                        <div className="container-fluid">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-5">
                                    <label>Name/Surname</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-5">
                                    <label>Address</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-2 align-self-center text-center">
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Filters;
```

Comment: Hey! You might want to create a new state entry in your children components called `filteredList` and then map trough your initial list using `Array.filter` method and assign it to your `filteredList`. That’s how you will get a filtered list without mutating any of your original values. If you will be still struggling with it, drop a line, I will make a full blown answer!

Comment: Can you write full answer please, I'm not clearly understand where to put that component

Answer (score 0):

One way to move forward (possibly the best way, IMO) is this:

Come up with a data model to describe a single "filter". This could be as simple as an object that describes a name string and an address string that items need to be filtered using. The design of this is up to you; pick whatever works out best.

Then, build two sets of behavior into `Speakers`:

1. The ability to receive filtration instructions from `Filters`. You can achieve this by writing a function in `Speakers` that acts as a callback function when something changes in `Filters`. Pass this function as a prop to `Filters` and have `Filters` call it when its state changes (meaning, when you get user interaction).
2. The ability to send this filter object *to* `List`. Every time the callback function is called, have `Speakers` send it down to `List`. You can achieve this by storing what `Filters` sends back in `Speakers`' state and passing that state item down to `List` as a prop. That should update `List`'s props every time `Filters` calls the callback function and thus affects `Speakers`' state.

Then, build behavior in `List` such that it changes its rendering behavior based on this filter object. Make sure to detect props updates so that it works on the fly.